# Close ActionBar Spinner programmatically or avoid opening it

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I'm trying to use the spinner in the `ActionBar` to provide account context in my app. There is also a "Add account" element at last position in the list. I'm using `ABS` and configure spinner appearance with `.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);`

So far so good.

The first time the user launch the app, this `spinner` will be empty, the only choice will be "Add account", it's also this text that is visible in the spinner current selection. What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect the user to the new account activity when the user clicks on the `spinner` (not in the opened list, but on the spinner itself). In my adapter, I could detect it and open the screen like that:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        ...
    }

    if (parent.getClass() == Spinner.class && ((Spinner) parent).getCount() == 1) { //"Hack" for initial click on "Add Account" in the spinner when it's empty
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AccountPreferenceActivity.class);
        ((HomeActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, HomeActivity.ACTIVITY_PREFERENCE_ACCOUNT);
    }

    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

My problem is that after filling the new form and getting back to the home screen, the spinner will be open and it's kind of ugly user experience.

My first attempt was to avoid opening the spinner in the getDropDownView method, but I failed to achieve it. I've then tried all kind of dirty workaround (make `spinner` disappear/reappear, focus on another field in the screen, simulate back button...), but nothing seems to work.

Do you have any idea how to achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: why don't to try simulating the click of the first item in the `Spinner` instead of starting the activity from the `getDropDownView`, by using `setSelectedNavigationItem` and then start the activity by using the navigationCallback.

Comment: @Varun I also tried that. As the label displayed is the selected one in the list, the callback doesn't provide me any new callback on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you just don't use `actionbar.setNavigationCallBacks` function?! 
here is an example that I'm using, maybe it helps:

```
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.navigations,
        R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(list, new OnNavigationListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    if (itemPosition == 0) {


    } else if (itemPosition == 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    return true;
    }
});
```

then in your **string.xml** define elements array that you wants to display in navigation list

```
<string-array name="navigations">
        <item>create account</item>
    </string-array>
```

---

**EDITED:**

Ok I find your answer, To achieve that, you have to just return `new View()` as a result of `getDropDownView(...)`

```
    @Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (! someSharedPreferencedObject.getBoolean("isAlreadyCreated", false)) {
    if (parent.getClass() == Spinner.class && ((Spinner) parent).getCount() == 1) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, UserSettingActivity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
    return new View(mContext);
    }
} else {
    return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
}
}
```

Comment: That's what I currently do. But the problem is that the displayed item is already consider as "selected" so the onNavigationItemSelected isn't called a second time when clicking on it.

Comment: @Hrk Ok! here's your solution, your have to just return new View() as result of getDropDownView(...). I update my answer to make it clear, It's working for me

Comment: I've just try your second solution. It doesn't seem to work neither :( The spinner is still open when I come back from my opened activity)

Comment: @Hrk I'm pretty sure it should work! be careful, don't forget first `if` because I think `getDropDownView()` will get called at least 2 times when there is just one item in spinner.  for start you can just return `new View(mContext)` without calling `super.getDropDownView(...)` too see it is working ;)

Comment: You're right, if I always return new View(context), the spinner doesn't appear. I will play by myself in debug mode to get exactly what I want when I will have more time during next days. Thanks ! I give you the bounty before it expires ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use **SherlockAction** bar

```
setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
```

To stop spinner use :-

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

To Restart Spinner use:-

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all and has nothing to do with the spinner, no ?

Comment: try to use action bar in android it helps to show spinner on action bar.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using through ABS

Comment: what are you using custom action bar or default action? bar.setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried invalidating the spinner's adapter / resetting it? It may have the desired effect.

Otherwise, if I understood what you're trying to achieve correctly, you could rather easily add at textual "Action button" as an options menu item at first to lead to the add account screen.

After you're back and there's an active account, you can populate a the spinner with the adapter only / invalidate the options menu.